# Did Tony Abbott suggest that men might be better suited to leadership positions?

Tags: politics, quotes, australia, tony-abbott

Apparently Australian politician, [Tony Abbott](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Abbott) suggested men are better at [leadership](http://www.smh.com.au/opinion/political-news/transcript-of-julia-gillards-speech-20121010-27c36.html) in 1998:

> He has said, and I quote, in a discussion about women being
>   under-represented in institutions of power in Australia, the
>   interviewer was a man called Stavros. The Leader of the Opposition
>   says “If it's true, Stavros, that men have more power generally
>   speaking than women, is that a bad thing?” Advertisement And then a
>   discussion ensues, and another person says “I want my daughter to have
>   as much opportunity as my son.” To which the Leader of the Opposition
>   says “Yeah, I completely agree, but what if men are by physiology or
>   temperament, more adapted to exercise authority or to issue command?”

Now I tried to find the whole speech. I expected this to be easy, as such a comment would be political dynamite and Labour would be stupid not to be shouting this from the rooftops.
So I did some Google searches:

[Search 1](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22If%20it%27s%20true,%20Stavros,%20that%20men%20have%20more%20power%20generally%20speaking%20than%20women,%20is%20that%20a%20bad%20thing%22&hl=en&qscrl=1&biw=1303&bih=683&sa=X&ei=Vm91UOCHL-XqiAfhroDgBA&ved=0CAwQpwUoBg&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min%3a,cd_max:1/10/2012&tbm=)
[Search 2](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22I%20want%20my%20daughter%20to%20have%20as%20much%20opportunity%20as%20my%20son%22%20tony%20abbott&hl=en&qscrl=1&biw=1303&bih=683&sa=X&ei=FnB1UOXPFqatiQe9qoDoBQ&ved=0CAwQpwUoBg&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min%3a,cd_max:1/1/2012&tbm=)
[Search 3](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22I%20want%20my%20daughter%20to%20have%20as%20much%20opportunity%20as%20my%20son%22%20tony%20abbott&hl=en&qscrl=1&biw=1303&bih=683&sa=X&ei=FnB1UOXPFqatiQe9qoDoBQ&ved=0CAwQpwUoBg&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min%3a,cd_max:1/1/2012&tbm=#hl=en&qscrl=1&tbs=cdr:1,cd_max:1/1/2012&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22more%20adapted%20to%20exercise%20authority%20or%20to%20issue%20command%22%20tony%20abbott&oq=%22more%20adapted%20to%20exercise%20authority%20or%20to%20issue%20command%22%20tony%20abbott&gs_l=serp.3...42999.45970.0.46297.15.15.0.0.0.0.223.3019.0j8j7.15.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.WLDYh7qmmYo&pbx=1&fp=1&bpcl=35243188&biw=1303&bih=683&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&cad=b&sei=K3F1UOTuMYujiAfhwYCoBQ)

Couldn't find any major newspapers with the quotes before today.

Comment: Bit more detail given by Anthony Albanese, but as this reference is also from yesterday it doesn't prove anything. http://anthonyalbanese.com.au/transcript-of-doorstop-senate-courtyard-parliament-house-4

Useful information to search with - round table discussion from 1998.
Also there is "Michael Costa"

Comment: Even the article you link to doesn't claim that Abbot said men are better at leadership. Even according to the claim, all he did was question the assumption of other speakers that increasing the representation of women in leadership was *ipso facto* a good thing.

Comment: As much as I dislike the man, he hasn't said anything noteworthy here, he sid "But what if" - he didn't make any claim that they were...

Comment: The body of the question asks "Did he really say this quote?" where the title implicitly also asks "Did he mean what his detractors claim?" The last couple of comments seem to be focussed on the second question. I suggest you clarify which is the one you want answered.

Comment: @Oddthinking: I am interested in whether this was said or not

Comment: 1998 was earlier internet days so I'm unsure whether you will find much contemporary references on-line to it. Thing is - it's pretty likely he said what is quoted, as it's been said outside parliament and he hasn't challenged or sued about it (from my perspective).

Comment: @NotJarvis has Abbott threatened to sue anyone about anything since "Goodbye Jerusalem"?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Dunno. But he could at least deny it - and make Gillard look silly for stating something that is false, if it was false. Politicians rarely miss an opportunity to point out factual errors by their opponents

Answer (score 3):

> 1998: Tony Abbott, at round table that included Michael Costa, then a
>   minister from New South Wales.
>
> Tony Abbott: “If it’s true, Stavros, that men have more power,
>   generally speaking, than women, is that a bad thing?”
>
> Costa: “Clearly it’s a bad thing.”
>
> Abbott: “Why is that, Michael?”
>
> Costa: “I want my daughter to have as much opportunity as my son.”
>
> Abbott: “Yeah, I completely agree, but what if men are by physiology
>   or temperament more adapted to exercise authority or to issue
>   commands?”
>
> Costa: “Well see, I don’t believe that. What I do think is that we
>   should never be in a situation where women have got to define their
>   notions of success and self worth by negating a traditional role. But
>   in terms of the power structure I think it’s very hard to deny that
>   there is an under-representation of women.”
>
> Abbott: “But now there’s an assumption that that is a bad thing.”

http://anthonyalbanese.com.au/transcript-of-doorstop-senate-courtyard-parliament-house-4

Comment: Page not found - we already knew it was from that website anyway

Comment: The Google cache still has it. (I don't think this is an answer. I am just testifying that this is a fair record of what that page used to say, before it was taken down.)

Comment: I wonder why it was taken down...

Comment: @Oddthinking - Why don't you consider this an answer? As per the comment above the OP was asking if this was said. Does this not count? Is it because you don't trust the Google cache? Maybe the answer should take a screenshot of the cached page.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79: The OP was skeptical that the conversation happened as claimed - he couldn't find any contemporary quotes. This answer did not provide a contemporary quote - it was just a recent repeat of the claim.

Comment: @Oddthinking - Ah, OK. I thought being on Anthony Albanese site made it sound legit. But if it a repeat of the claim then understand it doesn't count.